# Cannot find the right date format (NSDateFormatter) for this

Tags: ios, string, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I cannot convert this kind of strings to NSDate, please help me out here. What am I doing wrong below?

```
dateString = @"201302051614461";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMddHHmmSSSSS"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"dateString: %@", dateString);
NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

This returns with an empty date.

Comment: And have no debug information on this.

Comment: To help me understand the seconds part of the time, could you try date string `201302051614` and `YYYYMMddHHmm` and tell me what the output is please

Comment: First off, don't use YYYY.

Comment: @HotLicks in favour of? yyyy?

Comment: And why are you trying to get fractional seconds without getting seconds?

Comment: In favor of [the right one](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: You might be making assumptions about the desired output. @Geri.. What is your desired output please?

Comment: @JamesWebster - What does the "desired output" have to do with anything.  It's either an NSDate or it isn't.

Comment: @HotLicks Your answer describes what I mean. "YYYY will give you the wrong year in many cases", it's the other cases I was talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I break it like this `2013 02 05 16 14 46 1`
Then the format string is `@"yyyyMMddHHmmssS`

Answer (score 1):

`@"yyyyMMddHHmmssS"` -- YYYY will give you the wrong year in many cases, and capitol `S` is for fractional seconds.