# iOS Finding the time passed since a specific date

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I have been playing with NSDate and NSTimeInterval to try and get the time passed since a specific date, but I am not having much luck.

I want to specify an exact constant date (Jan 5th 2012 2PM) and calculate the time passed in Years, Hours, Min, Sec and display this on the screen as a counter.

It seems simple enough; however, browsing through code has yet to prove successful for me.

I also want to see total time in a years months days mins secs format. I appreciate any help, thanks!

This an example I have found that I don't know how to customize:

```
NSCalendar *c = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *d1 = [NSDate date];
NSDate *d2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1340323201];//2012-06-22
NSDateComponents *components = [c components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:d2 toDate:d1 options:0];
NSInteger diff = components.minute;

NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit
```

Comment: code? what you have done so far?

Comment: The best thing I have found so far is this:

Comment: NSCalendar *c = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *d1 = [NSDate date];
NSDate *d2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1340323201];//2012-06-22
NSDateComponents *components = [c components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:d2 toDate:d1 options:0];
NSInteger diff = components.minute;

NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit

Comment: Have you looked at the spec for NSCalendar?

Comment: in the line `NSDateComponents *components = [c components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:d2 toDate:d1 options:0];` you has to include all the components that you want, not only the `NSHourCalendarUnit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [tkanzakic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1411844/tkanzakic) said,

```
NSDateComponents* components = [c components:(NSYearCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:d1 toDate:d2 options:0] ;
NSLog(@"%ld years, %ld hours, %ld minutes, %ld seconds",  components.year, components.hour, components.minute, components.second) ;
```

Comment: This is great! The only problem is how to I make d2 equal to Jan 5th 2012 2pm so that it is giving me the proper time frame?

Comment: @KyleBegeman - And you want someone to do that for you, vs figuring out how to use NSCalendar or NSDateFormatter to do it?

Comment: Kyle, see @HotLicks's & Inder's answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712801/cannot-find-the-right-date-format-nsdateformatter-for-this/14713004